# can't import module into react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, import, npm-install

im new to react, and am trying to import an npm module from online. I used  `npm install --save flag-icon-css` to install the package. It seems to have installed correctly and i now have a folder for the module in the node_modules folder. However i am getting the following error `./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'flag-icon-css' in 'C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\Web Development\React\Projects\clock\src'`. 
Can anyone explain to me where im going wrong?

my import statements

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import ButtonClick from './Components/UserInputs.js';
  import Flags from 'flag-icon-css'
```

i also had these warnings when i installed the module

```
[npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.14.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.6 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})][1]
```

considering the module is in the same folder as react and react-dom i assumed i could use the same method to import it

and this is where i found the package https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css

here is my json file

```
{
  "name": "clock",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "create-react-app": "^3.0.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules and package-json and npm i again

Answer (score 0):

Try `import Flags from 'flag-icon-css'/flag-icon.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

Delete your package-lock.js and node_modules folder and then run `npm install`

Normally you would be careful when doing this because this will install any new releases of a package that you might not have designed your system around. But since it is a new project this should be fine for you.

Comment: package-lock.json*

Comment: `Module not found` is a webpack/babel error. This would only help clean up the warning from the install but unfortunately not solve the problem.

Comment: Good point. @seanBaker, are  you using webpack/babel?  I guess a better question would be, are you using ES6 and above?

Comment: i am using babel yes

Comment: Can you provide your package.json, please

Comment: Depending on what is in your package.json, this might be what you need. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/

Comment: Follow instructions for the babel plugin from.. babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import